# how can I record Gboard typing in other apps from a service

Tags: android, android-service, gboard

What I want to do is to make an Android app with the same functionality callable by typing special words into the Google keyboard at any moment in which it is open (even if it is used into another app).

The easiest solution to achieve this is by making my own keyboard and let the user set it as default but I would prefer to insert this functionality to the Gboard so the user does not have to change his keyboard application

So the question is:
How can I know from a service what's typed into the Gboard even when the keyboard is used by other applications?
is it possible?

Comment: Seems like a tricky way to steal passwords.

Comment: Gergely Kőrössy  Yes it seems... But this would be illegal. Luckily my app DOES NOT use internet connection so it is not his purpose 